# SQL find the oldest date of a book and its author

Tags: postgresql

Given a table "book" like the following

```
[name] [date] [author]
bookA   2019-08-12 Charles
bookB   2020-09-30 Jane
bookC   2019-08-12 Adam
```

The desires output is the following (find the oldest date and if the date are the same order by author)

```
[name] [date] [author]
bookC   2019-08-12 Adam
bookA   2019-08-12 Charles
```

I tried the following but the output was just the listing of all books in the order of the authors.

```
SELECT author, min(date)
FROM book
GROUP BY author
ORDER BY author;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select author,date from book
where date=(select min(date) from book)
order by author
```